# Wrong value os button item is being send using php

Tags: php, html

I have this apply page where i'm listing different jobs one can apply for each job has specific values and id, i'm listing all the values dynamically.

i'm printing the sql data inside an html table, now what i wanted to do was when i click on apply in want to process and send the job id to another page, but what is happening is same job id is being sent to the process page , regardless os which row's apply button i click on

1.apply.php

```
<?php 
include("db.php");
session_start();
$result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM news_upload order by id desc");
?>


<form action='process.php' method='post'>
    <table class="table table-bordered">  
        <tr>  
            <th width="5%">Job ID</th> 
            <th width="13%">Apply</th>                             
            <th width="10%">Date Uploaded</th>  
            <th width="33%">Job Title</th> 
            <th width="22%">Education</th> 
            <th width="10%">Salary</th>  
            <th width="12%">Location</th>
            <th width="33%">Last Date of Apply</th>
        </tr>      
        <tbody>
        <?php  
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            echo "<tr>";
            echo '<td><input type="text" name="name" value="'.$row['id'].'"></td>';
            echo '<td> <input width="10px" id="view" type="submit" name="submit" value="Apply"></td>';
            echo "<td>".$row['created_at']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['heading']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['education']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['salary_max']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['location']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['last_date']."</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        ?>
        </tbody>
    </form>
```

2. process.php

   ```
   <?php 
   session_start();
   if (isset($_POST['name'])){
       $name = $_POST['name'];
       echo $name;
       //echo("Selected Radio Button is".$button);
   }
   ?>
   ```

Comment: use ajax call to perform apply action.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same name for the multiple elements. That is the reason the value is overriding.

For eg., Consider the name of the element as the index of the array. If you assign different values to the same index in the array, the values will be overridden.

The same is the case with form elements. So instead of

`echo '<td><input type="text" name="name" value="'.$row['id'].'"></td>';`

Try this,

`echo '<td><input type="text" name="name[]" value="'.$row['id'].'"></td>';`

Make Sure to change the Form tag from

`<form action='process.php' method='post'>`

to

`<form action='process.php' method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data">`

This makes the name field unique and you'll receive the desired values in the other page.

Hope this helps.

Comment: can you help me what would i change in the process.php page

Comment: using this method i'm having trouble processing the value on next page

Comment: Ok. I have edited the answer. By this edited answer you dont have to change anything in process.php file.

Comment: Array to string conversion in C:\wamp64\www\apply\process.php on line 9 getting this error

Comment: Done use `echo $name;`. Please use `print_r($name);` or `var_dump($name);` to print an array.

Comment: what this is doing is  sending me values of all job id's on clicking apply , i'm trying to get the specific job id of a table row in which i'm clicking apply